# не устанавливается текст в TextView

Tags: textview, android-textview

investactivity.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 55"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 11" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

InvestActivity.java

```html
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InvestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.investactivity);
        TextView textEl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textEl.setText("23232323");
    }
}
```

Comment: А статический текст отображается который вы в верстке указываете? Ошибки выдает какие то?

Comment: статический отображается, ошибок нет

Comment: Очень странно, а после того как вы в коде устанавливаете текст - статический исчезает или остается?

Comment: Вообщем, я запустил ваш код -  у меня все работает!